# While outputting an array with a for loop, how can i output all of the contents into a single, new div? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am outputting the values of an array with a for loop by using innerHTML +=, in order to add to the contents of a current div- let's call it div1 (known as currentQuestions in the code).

The function which outputs the array values is to be used multiple times, as the values stored within the array change from user input. This means that div1 will have a growing list of output.

However the problem is that for each group of data iterated by the array, i need them to be stored together in their own div (within div1), separate from other groups generated by a different call of the same function.

they dont need to have unique IDs, but they are needed to call a function onclick which will affect only the div that is clicked.

This is what i have so far:

```
arrayLength = answers.length
for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++)
    {
    document.getElementById('currentQuestions').innerHTML += answers[j] + '<br />'
    }
```

As you can see, all i have is the for loop so far. I cant add a div to the innerHTML because then it will create a div for each iteration rather than one div for the full iteration of the array.

I'm out of ideas. Thoughts?

Comment: Whats the problem with adding 'div' outside the 'for' ?

Comment: Just create the `div` and attach the event handler before the loop.

Comment: If i create the div outside of the innerHTML insertion then it will create a new subdiv, but the contents of the loop will be placed within the main div, outside of the subdiv, rather than nested in it

Comment: You really should get rid of `innerHTML`. You can add elements where ever you want to by using DOM manipulation. Please get familiar with [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement), [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) and [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping posting this would allow me to expand my knowledge, so I`ll look into those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the div and attach the event handler before the loop, something like this:

```
var subdiv = document.createElement('div'), // Creates a new element to the DOM
    arrayLength = answers.length;

subdiv.addEventListener('click', function () {...}); // Attach a click listener

for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {
    subdiv.innerHTML += answers[j] + '<br />'; // Add some content to newly-created DIV
}
document.getElementById('currentQuestions').appendChild(subdiv); // Append the newly-created element to the document.
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your life easier and try jQuery...

This example would take the html within a div they clicked on and append it to the #currentQuestions div...

```
$('body').on('click', '.class_of_div_they_click_on', function(event) {
    var div_content = $(this).html();
    $("#currentQuestions").append(div_content + '<br>');
});
```

Comment: No reason jQuery could not be suggested.

Comment: put it in comment instead.